# frame drop on game initial start

Tags: libgdx

I am loading all my assets using the AssetManager in my splashscreen and I dispose the assetmanager properly. I am also using a tiled map and various actors as well as a stage. When I create the stage and initialize all actors initially and setTheScreen on it  the game's frame rate is always something like:
45,47,50,52,47,55 and then it recovers to 60 and then it never drops below 59. So on a start the game always lags slightly for about 5-10 seconds and then it recovers and always maintain 60 FPS. Has anyone experienced something like that, is it normal?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: it's better to give us some code there are some possible answers. BTW i had a same problem ,i handle it by loading all my assets in a loadingscreen and initialize important objects int there. It reduces delay time for reaching 60fps. also you should be fps independent for example for changing your position of your objectsdon't do something like this `x+=5` instead use `x+= delta*5`

Comment: I think..that's exactly the problem..I will try to move all the heavy objects initialization in the splashscreen..However, because I have different levels, so I don't know which levele will be picked..so I will display some loading screen on top of the stage for 5 seconds until the game gets to 60fps and then will remove it..angry birds are doing a similar thing when loading levels.thanks